# Why is this chaining method not working?

Tags: c++

It's a simple counter. The method `add` is being called to increment the private variable `count` by 1 by default. I am returning the `Counter` class from the function so that it may be chained, but when I look at the output, it gives me 1 when I expect it to be 3 because I called `add` three times.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;

class Counter {
    public:
        Counter() : count(0) {}

        Counter add() {
            ++count; return *this;
        }

        int getCount() {
            return count;
        }
    private:
        int count;
};

int main() {

    Counter counter;

    counter.add().add().add();

    cout << counter.getCount();

}
```

Comment: Returning `Counter` makes a copy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The whole idea of chaining idiom is based on accessing *the same*, *original* object in each chained call. This is usually achieved by returning a *reference* to the original object from each modifying method. This is how your `add` should have been declared

```
    Counter &add() { // <- note the `&`
        ++count; return *this;
    }
```

That way, each application of `add` in your chained expression will modify *the same*, *original* object.

In your original code, you return a temporary *copy* of the original object from `add`. So, each additional application of `add` (after the first one) works on a temporary copy, modifies that copy and produces yet another temporary copy. All those temporary copies disappear without a trace at the end of the full expression. For this reason, you never get to see the effects of any `add` calls besides the very first one.

Comment: What if there was an asterisk (\*) prefixing `add`: `Counter *add() {...` What would *that* mean?

Comment: @user6607  It means your returning a pointer of `Counter`.  You could accomplish the same thing if you `return this` and change `counter.add().add().add()` to `counter->add()->add()->add()`

Comment: @MartyE: It would be `counter.add()->add()->add()` in that case. The first one would still be a `.`.